Нужна ли запятая (или другой знак) перед обоими "кто"?
Люди несли деньги в ломбард, чтобы выкупить кто кольцо, кто часы.

Правильно:
Люди несли деньги в ломбАрд, // чтобы вЫкупить, кто кольцО, кто часЫ.
Пояснение
Это ССП, 4 предикативные основы: придаточное цели (союз чтобы) и два однородных неполных придаточных  (кто кольцо, кто часы) в позиции однородных членов: или кольцо, или часы.
Контаминация разных структур. В этих случаях более сложная конструкция (предложение, оборот речи) выступает в качестве  структурного элемента (например, одного слова) при построении другой конструкции.
ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ
Возможно и другое толкование: ...выкупить, // кто кольцо, кто часы.
Можно считать, что здесь бессоюзная связь, обозначенная запятой. В этом случае все проще: нужно только определить вид отношений и выбрать знак. Отношения изъяснительные (вмещающего типа): выкупить (что?).
